# jenkins fails to install with no error on debian 7

Tags: jenkins, debian

i'm trying to get jenkins running on debian 7 but i keep getting this error while apt-get install jenkins is running.

`Setting up dbus (1.6.8-1) ...`

`Failed to open connection to "system" message bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory`

`[ ok ] Starting system message bus: dbus.`

Also i get the message that jenkins is started at the end and no error message:

`[ ok ] Starting Jenkins Continuous Integration Server: jenkins.`

but `/etc/init.d/jenkins status` gives me the output that jenkins is not running. also ls -alh /var/lib/jenkins gives me an empty folder.

So the install fails with no error.

This is the way i'm running the install:

`wget -q -O - http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | apt-key add -`

`sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'`

`apt-get update`

`apt-get install jenkins`

Has anyone of you tried installing jenkins on a fresh debian 7?

looking forward for helping answers.

kind regards and thanks in advance

Comment: i checked for the file/dir in /var/run/dbus named system_bus_socket and it exists, googled that right away upfront.

Comment: with the freshly released debian 7.1 the dbus problem is non existent anymore but still `/var/lib/jenkins` is empty and `/etc/init.d/jenkins start` will say OK but `/etc/init.d/jenkins status` will tell me jenkins not running. makes sense, when no files exist in the jenkins folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i solved the problem finally.

I expected the Java SDK to have the right JRE in it, so i downloaded it from the Oracle website: `jdk1.7.0_21-x64-linux.tar.gz` after installing and registering this to my machine it worked `java -version` and `javac -version`.

Problem was the version of this JRE did not work with Jenkins so thanks to @wako, i installed openjdk-7-jre and i have now two jre's running on my machine but jenkins started finally. need to figure out if openjdk-7-jre suits my plans or if i need to fall back to Debian 6.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with apt-get and not with Jenkins -
please make sure you run it as root.

Can try to install (or upgrade) another package, to confirm.

Comment: i'm running a VM for testing purposes and work on root. any other ideas?

Comment: Sure - your VM is blocked from the network (or at least from the DNS)... Often the firewall on the host OS is blocking access to the VM.

Comment: That can't be it, i built an installation document, because i'm testing a new setup and the SAME document works on debian 6 just fine. just in debian 7 i can't get jenkins to run/install correctly

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on the debian 7 freshly installed, via the light version of debian 7 with the ssh server only installed.
First I add the repository as you specified it, try to install jenkins but some dependencies were broken (daemon-psmisc-java2-runtime).
To solve the problem I did an:

> apt-get -f upgrade
>    And it was OK

To complete the installation of jenkins you will need apache2 and java-jre

apt-get install apache2 openjdk-7-jre

Comment: Thanks, i'll give this a try and let you know.

Comment: To complete the installation of jenkins you will need apache2 and java-jre

 apt-get install apache2
 apt-get install openjdk-7-jre

Comment: there isn't a documented need for apache2 to install jenkins also it worked on debian 6 without apache2. i installed the latest java sdk (.tar.gz from oracle's website). the `apt-get -f upgrade` doest not do anything for me.

Comment: Indeed apache isn't needed

Comment: I'm also running a VM, you can eventually bridge your network interface. This seems to be a system issue with dbus not properly installed.

Comment: as of the comment on my original post above, with debian 7.1 the dbus problem got fixed? but there is still another problem to be sorted out. have you tried to install it on a debian 7/7.1?

Comment: Host: Windows 7
Guest: Debian 7 (Small CD) http://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst
Ethernet is in bridge mode
I have installed jenkins and the JRE 7
I had some problems with some system component but with a -f upgrade option solve it

Comment: Okay, i'm running on a Windows 8 as Host and Debian 7 netinst as minimal installation (just core). My Network is NAT as i'm restricted by Proxy config to use this. I'm running some routine installations upfront, because i need to prepare the system for production use (this is the testinstallation, it will be installed on a hardware machine later). So i install make, g++, python, ssh, git, git-core, gitolite, nodejs then the somewhere above mentioned oracle java jdk (jre included) and then jenkins. On debian 6 this all worked fine. On debian 7 i now have to use openjdk-7-jre as you mentioned,ty